# pip installed modules and alternate paths

Tags: python, pip

For various reasons, I need to install a python module somewhere outside the default location. `pip install --prefix` would seem like the right thing, but I'm having problems:

```
$ pip install --prefix /tmp/foo protobuf-3.2.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/foo/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/tmp/foo/lib64/python2.7/site-packages')
>>> sys.path
['', '/tmp/foo/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/tmp/foo/lib64/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> import google.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

But if I install it in the default location (which I cannot do in production):

```
$ sudo pip install protobuf-3.2.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.protobuf
>>> google.protobuf.__version__
'3.2.0'
```

I assume my invocation of the `pip` command is wrong, or there is something else I need to do to get at that module at runtime. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to use virtual env. of python

Comment: there is a chance the package was installed to `/tmp/foo/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead of `lib64`, but in either case `virtualenv` is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible solution for you would be the use of "virtualenv". You can install required packages whose scope will only be limited to the virtual environment. Also it will ignore all the previously installed packages that are already in your main repository. For a quick start, follow this link: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

`--ignore-installed` is to force all dependencies to be reinstalled using this new prefix. This looks to be the problem you're having. You can use `--install-option` multiple times to add any of the options you can use with python setup.py install with `--prefix`.

I am not sure why you want this path to be different. You should probably initialize a virtual environment to keep your modules project specific. However, if this is necessary for your use case, do the above.